# just show plotpoints if not enough data for boxplot using ggspot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a small data set (charted below), and I'm getting the beginnings of boxplots even though I don't have enough data for a complete one. Is it possible for ggplot2 to only render them as plot points when there's less than four?  Ideally making them distinct in shape from the outliers shown below.

[image: Result of a small data set]

Comment: Create two datasets; one with groups n() > 5 and one with groups n() <= 5, and then plot them in separate ggplot2-layers?

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends what is your biggest `n`. Is it 30 or more like 300?
If you have few points and want to plot your data using boxplots I think you could use boxplots and points together in the same plot. It's always better to show the individual data points if you don't have too many.

```
ggplot(your_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point()
```

If you could provide an example of your data, I'd be easier to address your question.